# Diagramming arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create these two diagrams (each on a standalone document). I've already searched for something similar and I've found several examples using tips: unluckily none of them is customizable. Could someone help?

[image]

Comment: Hello. You neither accepted the answer below nor asking for an improvement yet. Feel free do it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing too fancy here, only nodes and clever placement. Probably possible to do with trees, but if you only have those little ones to do...

[image: Diagramming arguments 1]

[image: Diagramming arguments 2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=5mm,
        every node/.style={inner xsep=0pt}]
        
        \node (A) {$6$};
        \node[below = of A,anchor=40] (B) {$4+5$};
        \draw[->] (A) -- (A|-B.north);
        \draw (B.south west) -- (B.south east);
        
        \node[below= of B, anchor=40] (C) {$2+3$};
        \draw[->] (B) -- (B|-C.north);
        \draw (C.south west) -- (C.south east);
        
        \node[below= of C,anchor=north] (D) {$1$};
        \draw[->] (C) -- (D);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=8mm,
        every node/.style={inner xsep=0pt}]
        
        \node (A) {$11+12+13$};
        \draw (A.south west) -- (A.south east);
        
        \node[below right = of A] (C) {$10$};
        \node[above right = of C] (B) {$9$};
        
        \draw[->] (A) -- (C.north west);
        \draw[->] (B.south) -- (C.north east);
        
        \node[below= of C] (D) {$8$};
        \draw[->] (C) -- (D);       
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!!